# Onchange select item value set on the next column input field for each row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the selected item's `data-price` to set on the next column's input field. It's working for first row but not working for each row.

How do I get this done?

```
<td>
  <select class="clientType" name="type[]">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
    <option data-price="3" value="3">R</option>
    <option data-price="10" value="10">EB</option>
    <option data-price="3" value="3">ND</option>
    <option data-price="" value="">Special</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input class="clientAmt" type="number" name="amount[]">
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.clientType').change(function () {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
    })    
})
```

Comment: use `$(this).next('td').find('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));`

Comment: Same code...Working for me... https://jsfiddle.net/5uf3h7Lm/

Comment: @AjuJohn because only 1 row with multiple row i doubt it will work

Comment: @guradio : 1 row with multiple row?? i didn't get..

Comment: Although there is no need to loop...

Comment: using this `$(this).each(function() {` so i assume there are more select :) and using table tr so more rows to come @AjuJohn

Comment: But here click event is binded for select. So at a time only one select will be changed. :) No matter how many selects with same classes are on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `each` and go to the `closest` row to `find` the `.clientAmt`

```
$('.clientType').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('.clientType').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="clientType" name="type[]">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
        <option data-price="3" value="3">R</option>
        <option data-price="10" value="10">EB</option>
        <option data-price="3" value="3">ND</option>
        <option data-price="" value="">Special</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="clientAmt" type="number" name="amount[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="clientType" name="type[]">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
        <option data-price="3" value="3">R</option>
        <option data-price="10" value="10">EB</option>
        <option data-price="3" value="3">ND</option>
        <option data-price="" value="">Special</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="clientAmt" type="number" name="amount[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** The problem in your code is

```
 $(this).each(function() {
    $('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
 })
```

Here `$(this)` is just one `select` element, so your loop will be executed only once anyways. The main problem is this `$('.clientAmt').val(...)` Here you are selecting all the `input` elements with the class `clientAmt`, The selector returns you array of elements, And when you set any attribute on this array of elements it will be applied only for the first element in the array. Hence it always applies to your first `input`. You have to select the appropriate input and assign the value to only this one.

**Solution :**
So you have two options to resolve this

**1)** Using **parent().next()** : use `parent()` on the select tag which will give you the `td` of this select tag and then do `next` on this `td` which will take you to the next `td` that has the `input` in it. Now set the value of this `input`

```
$('.clientType').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});
```

**2)** Using **closest('tr').find('.clientAmt')**: use `closest()` to find the closest `tr` which wraps this entire row, that is the `tr` which wraps this `td` and other `td` which holds the `input`. Now from this `tr` find the `input` with class `clientAmt` with in it

```
$('.clientType').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.clientAmt').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});
```

Comment: when dynamically add row then this function work no more @Reddy

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    let next_select = $(this);
// console.log(next_select.toArray())
    if (!next_select.parent().parent().next().find('select').length) {
        next_select.parent().parent().parent().next().find('input[type="text"]').click()
        console.log(next_select.parent().parent().parent().next());
    } else if (next_select.parent().parent().next().find('select').prop("disabled")) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            next_select.parent().parent().next().find('select').select2('open')
        }, 1000)
        console.log('b');
    } else if (next_select.parent().parent().next().find('select').length) {
        next_select.parent().parent().next().find('select').select2('open')
        console.log('c');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to how this is relevant to the question at hand. In general, refrain from posting answers that contain nothing but code.